# Get X posts for all post types on Taxonomy term archive

Tags: wp-query, archives

I'm working on a tabbed archive page for taxonomy terms.

Ultimately, I want each tab to show the 10 most recent posts for an individual post type with a "see all" link at the bottom of the tab that will direct visitors to a Post Type archive filtered by a taxonomy term.

I know I can achieve this relatively easily with multiple queries and something along the lines of:

```
<section class="tab" id="tab1">
    <?php $query1 ?>
    [loop content here]
</section>

<section class="tab" id="tab2">
    <?php $query2 ?>
    [loop content here]
</section>

[...]
```

For the templates in question, I'll only be using 4 tabs, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this with a single query.

What I'd really like to output is something more like:

```
<article class="custom-type1">
    [Listing content]
</article>

<article class="custom-type2">
    [Listing content]
</article>

<article class="custom-type1">
    [Listing content]
</article>

<article class="custom-type3">
    [Listing content]
</article>

<article class="custom-type2">
    [Listing content]
</article>

[...]
```

Then I would use the tabs to turn visibility on/off for specific CSS classes. (I also think this second option would look nicer for visitors with JS disabled).

Comment: *for visitors with JS disabled* Do not try to please the absolute minimum which do not use JS.

Comment: Why not? I've always felt that JS should _enchance_ the user experience not define it.